# Como utilizar Google Maps API com Google Directions API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-maps, google-api

Oi,

Eu estou a usar a API do Google Maps e quero ser capaz de clicar, por exemplo, num ponto previamente criado no mapa e obter as direcções apartir da minha localização até ao ponto seleccionado. Para isso estou a tentar usar a API Directions da Google. 
Estou a tentar fazer isto com node.js.

Primeira questão: É necessário obter outra api key, sendo que já tenho a api key da API do Google Maps?

Segunda questão: Como implementá-las ambas, selecionando um ponto no mapa e depois obter as direcções até esse ponto desde a minha localização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre a primeira questão você pode usar a mesma key, só tem que verificar se a API  Directions está habilitada na sua conta(https://console.cloud.google.com/) e se a sua key não esta limitada a uma API especifica.

Sobre a segunda pergunta, você ja consegue avançar utilizando esses links.
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: eu já estive a pesquisar e não encontrei o que queria. Eu tenho uma app com um mapa que tem vários pontos cada um numa certa localização, as suas coordenadas estão a armazenadas numa Base de Dados (mongoDB). E quero aplicar o api directions a estes pontos para que quando carregar num ponto me dê as direções desde a minha posição actual até o ponto selecionado.

Comment: Veja se esse exemplo te ajuda.
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple